# Finding height of a div from inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a searchbar on my index, that updates while I am searching and it add or remove results as you write more text and it narrows down.

The results are then listen inside a DIV located on another page that I access from the index by iFrame on my site.

My problem now is that I want to get the height of the result-div and send it back from "within" the iFrame to the page where the iFrame is located so I can change the height based on the content as it changes.

Ive looked all over and tried many ways. But it all boils down to that: I cant get the height of the result-div-page when I request it from my index page.

Comment: <page><iframe/></page> You can get iframe height with js inside your page or your iframe, but you can't calculate it's height inside iframe and use that value inside page, they have different scopes, to do that kind of thing you would have to communicate between them with some webservice.

Comment: And from page, you can calculate the outer height of iframe, not a height of a div inside iframe, from what I know

Comment: Actually, if the `iframe src` is in the same origin as the main page, then you can access the `iframe` contents (and calculate the height).

Answer (score 0):

Okey. Here is the solution...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#search-frame" ).on('load', function() { 
        var search_div = $(this).contents().find("#table-results");
        var search_height     = search_div.height();
        $('#search-frame').css('height', search_height);
        });
});

</script>
```